# How do I image a LUKS system disk with Clonezilla without including all the empty space?

Tags: system-installation, luks, clonezilla

I have a 1 TB NVMe disk with Ubuntu 22 installed with vanilla options, except I used LVM, and enabled LUKS.  I'd like to image the disk for easy restores.  Simply backing up the files is not enough for me, because I also want to revert partition/LVM information when restoring.  However, I don't want to end up with a 1 TB image file that is 95% empty space.

How do I get Clonezilla to do this?  I can unlock/mount the encrypted volumes, and image them, but that doesn't maintain the underlying partition structure.  If I image the underlying partitions, it images the LUKS partitions like they're just a 900ish GB slab of binary.

What's a workaround here?

Comment: Have you tried to "Skip checking/repairing source file system" in expert mode? IMO this option will avoid including empty space in the image.

Comment: @YoushaAleayoub How would it be able to tell what is and isn't empty space without decrypting the drive?

Comment: @Ducan Marshall AFAIK LUKS does not automatically(by default) fill or over-write entire blocks. Only the Ubuntu installer will do this itself (in expert mode)

Comment: It doesn't, but it's an encrypted partition, so Clonezilla cannot see what is and isn't empty space.

Comment: So I think you can do this only by unlocking the device and filling free space by zeroes, then using DD by this way ` dd conv=sparse if=/dev/XYZ of=/tmp/myimage.raw`. This will punch zeroes from the image when reading.

Comment: Imaging the contents of the unlocked partition is not the problem.  The problem is conserving the partition/lvm structure.